# How to get value from .js file based on some field value in Java?

Tags: javascript, java

I have a .js file which contains a list of location and I want to pick a location based on it's 'type' with the help of Java code.

### This is the .js file:

```
var place_ac = {
    "Banglore": {
        "type": "no-metro",
        "lat": 1.440637,
        "lng": 103.800762
    },
    "Chennai": {
        "type": "metro",
        "lat": 1.316412,
        "lng": 103.882754
    },
    "New Delhi": {
        "type": "metro",
        "lat": 1.370194,
        "lng": 103.849425
    },
    "Bhopal": {
        "type": "no-metro",
        "lat": 1.388272,
        "lng": 103.905677
    },
    "Kolkata": {
        "type": "metro",
        "lat": 1.343024,
        "lng": 103.879485
    }
}
```

Now I want to get all the values which have type="metro".

Comment: Where do you want to get this information?  From your Java program or from the browser?

Comment: I have the above mentioned content in a file. I need to make a Java program which will read from this file and print the values based on the type filter.

Comment: Get rid of `var place_ac =` in the .js file and read the file in in Java and parse it as JSON. Then you can write your logic around that.

Comment: It would take a hell of a time if you are going to write parsing code from scratch. My best bet would be to search about GSON it's a library. You have to include that library in your code and voila by using gson predefined functions you can retrieve your required data from JSON or file which contains JSON data

Note: I haven't personally used GSON but I think that "var place_ac" will going to cause you a problem. So, as @manonthemat said you have to ditch that string.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question: [Capture the javascript return value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626783/capture-the-javascript-return-value-in-java)

It shows how to call JavaScript from java and capture any return value.

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery `json` parser:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(your var place_ac );
var v1 = obj['type'];
```

By using `javasript` `json` parser:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(your var place_ac );
var v2 = obj['type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call to the server sending this JSON object (from js file) in the ajax request. At server side, you can retrieve the ajax request using `request.getParameter` and convert into `JSONObject` (using `JSONArray`).

From this `JSONObject`, you can retrieve the required values in Java.